# How to read dual sim card phone number

Tags: xamarin.android

I want to get dual sim phone numbers .
I want code work on android v 4.2 and hiegher .
I used this code and did not work on Android devices.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />


   bt_.Click += delegate
            {

                tm = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(TelephonyService);
                String phonenumberstring = null;
                phonenumberstring = tm.Line1Number;

                Toast.MakeText(this, "phone " + phonenumberstring, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            };
```

Comment: I use your code and I can get the my phone number, but you said that it didn't work on Android devices, do you have any error message?

Comment: Did two sim numbers appear?

Comment: Nothing appears on the actual devices. Shown only by emulator

Comment: I have one sim card in android device to test, so I only get one sim numbers.